# Reading a large text file and storing info in a hash table?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, hash, gps

I have written a program using unity and c# that uses the gps location of my android device and it detects whether I am near a certain pre-defined location.
So far it is all working fine and the programme detects all the pre-defined locations and it informs me when I am near them.

I have achieved this by using streamreader that creates a string list that reads a text file line by line and stores it in elements within the inspector.

The elements get read every time the gps location changes using a loop to the end of list and it inspects the elements if any of them match the gps location.

The problem that I now have is that my database text file is getting very large it eventually errors because there are too many elements.

The text file is formatted like so

53.752 -2.481 Location1.

51.551 -3.271 Location2.

55.932 -4.037 Location3

and so on....

the database could be in the 1000's of items, where the first number is latitude, 2nd is longitude and 3rd is description

My question is would a hash table be best suited for this and if so how would I add the separate items to the list. I assume that the latitude and longitude would be the key and the location would be the pair.

I have tried to find examples but the ones I find all the information has been added in the script, ie

```
    Hashtable mytable = new Hashtable();// create a new hashtable called mytable

    //add all the elements that you want in the format key followed by pair
    mytable.Add(1, "Location1");
```

rather than reading the information form a text file.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hash is not going to solve a text file size issue.  The best solution is to use a real database instead of a text file.  You can download SQL Express for free from msdn which will solve the issue.

Comment: A list with thousands of items should cause no problems. Searching through this list is very performant, even when comparing latitude and longitude of each item, I would not optimize this before you really run into performance problems. How you read the items to create the list is another question, but has nothing to do with using a hashtable. Keeping the list in memory seems the logical solution to me, instead of reading it every time from the database/file.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, what do you think would be the best way to do it? I agree keeping it in memory would be the best way to do it rather than constantly reading it it but how exactly, I am not really sure on this

Comment: Just write a class `Location` with the properties `Latitude`, `Longitude` and `Name`, then create a list of type  `List<Location>`. Fill the list once and keep the variable of the list, there is no magic in this.

Comment: Unless I have miss-understood that is kind of what I have (I think). Here is a snippet of the code that I have just chopped down to  public class Location : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<string> info = new List<string>();
    public int linenumber;
    void Start()
    {
        info.Clear();
        linenumber  = 0;
        StreamReader r = File.OpenText(Application.persistentDataPath + "\\" + "myreadwritefile.txt");
        while (!r.EndOfStream)
        {string eachline = r.ReadLine();
            linenumber ++;
            info.Add(eachline);
        }
        r.Close();

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this way seems to work. Thanks for everybodys input, ot definitely steered me in the right direction.

```
public class Location : MonoBehaviour
{
   public int howmany;// how many lines are in the text file

  void Start()
    {
       List<string> fileLines = new List<string>(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Application.persistentDataPath + "\\" + "locationdatabase.txt"));
        howmany  = (fileLines.Count);
        Debug.Log(fileLines[4520]);// look at a particular line in the file
        Debug.Log(howmany);
}
```

}